# Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova, soap-client

I'm getting this error while invoking a Webservice from Phonegap Android app.

> 01-13 23:49:52.219: E/Web Console(529): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null at file:///android_asset/www/soapclient.js:158

Here is the relevant code:

```
var ns = (wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"] + "" == "undefined") ?
wsdl.documentElement.attributes.getNamedItem("targetNamespace").nodeValue :  
wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"].value;
```

Comment: Looks like `wsdl.documentElement` is `null` from the error. So check how `wsdl` is set and if it has the property `documentElement`

Answer (score 1):

it might because of cross Domain request, CORS
so either you have to include it into your heades

```
Accept: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

OR also use

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

OR also you can install the chrome extenstion

[Enable cors request extention in chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Hope it will help.